# How to fetch large sql data from Angular without timeout

Tags: angular, sql-server-2008

I am using Angular to fetch large data from sql server. The query itself takes time to finish (max of 5 minutes) due to the number of records need to load. When calling the stored procedure in Angular, it always prompt "*Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The statement has been terminated*". What is the best way to solve this kind of scenario?

Comment: 1. increase timeout for current request; 2. try to use virtual scroll for rendering large data; 3. best way - using pagination on server side

Comment: thanks @НикитаСереда! will go with the best suggested way.